# Model Binding with variable number of items in List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a model that can have a variable amount of items in a `List<T>`

In my view I then have the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    int count = Model.Data.Filters.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        <div>

        @Html.TextBox("filtervalue" + i)
        @Html.DropDownList("filteroptions"+i,Model.Data.Filters[i].FilterOptions)


        </div>
    }
    @Html.Hidden("LinkID", Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"])
}
```

Is there a way in my controller so I can set up the POST action method to bind to a model with variable items in it?

Also how would I construct the model to cope with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You coud use editor templates, it will be much easier:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Data.Filters)
    @Html.Hidden("LinkID", Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"])
}
```

and inside the editor template (`~/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/FilterModel.cshtml`) which will be automatically rendered for each element of the `Model.Data.Filters` collection:

```
@model FilterModel
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FilterValue)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFilterOption, Model.FilterOptions)
</div>
```

Now your POST controller action will simply look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(SomeViewModel model)
{
    // model.Data.Filters will be properly bound here
    ...
}
```

Thanks to editor templates you no longer have to write any foreach loops in your views or worry about how to name your input fields, invent some indexed, ... so that the default model binder recognizes them on postback.

Comment: I've seen this by Scott Hanselman which might work?? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: @Jon, yes that's how your markup should look like if you want the default model binder to work. Editor templates will generate such correct markup. Don't struggle with loops and indexes. You will have hard times ahead of you. There won't be any need of a loop. The editor template will be automatically invoked for each element of the collection. ASP.NET MVC recognizes that Filters is a collection and does this for you. Everything works on conventions. Respect the conventions and your views will be pretty and the model binder will work...

Comment: ... the name of the template is important though. For example if the `Filters` property is of type `IList<FilterModel>` or even `IEnumerable<FilterModel>` or `FilterModel[]` your editor template must be called `FilterModel.cshtml` and situated inside the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` or `~/Views/SomeControllerName/EditorTemplates` folders.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works as you explained. I didn't realise that EditorTemplates new about collections. You learn something new everyday.