# MVC3 Validate total for list of elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View Model that represents a total bill and list of parties that are splitting the bill.  The parties splitting the bill each take a certain percentage of the total (example: Party A takes 50%, Party B takes 20%, Party C takes 30%).

The model looks something like this:

```
public class BillModel
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<BillPartyModel> Parties { get; set; }
}

public class BillPartyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SplitPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I want to validate that the `SplitPercentage` for all parties totals to exactly 100.  I was initially tempted to add custom validation attribute to `SplitPercentage`, but I'm not sure how to sum all the values in the validator.  Could I perhaps add a custom validation attribute to `Parties` in the main model (and how would that work)?  Or does someone know a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I did as suggested below and ended up with this (using DataAnnotationsExtensions for the EqualTo tag):

*Model*

```
[EqualTo("TotalPercent", ErrorMessage = "Percentages do not add up to 100%.")]
public int SplitPercentage { get { return this.Allocations.Sum(a => a.Allocation); } }
public int TotalPercent { get { return 100; } }
```

*View*

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SplitPercentage)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SplitPercentage)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BillPartyModel)
```

...And then I just use a JavaScript OnChange event to update the AllocationTotal in order to get Client-Side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int Total { get { return Parties.Sum(p=>p.SplitPercentage); } }
```

Then when you are validating the model make sure Total = 100

Comment: You may add this calculated property into your viewmodel and add validation attribute to it. This will fire server-side validation.

Comment: I did like fredlegrain said and ended up with the info I noted above.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the [custom validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx) and create a editor template for your `List<BillPartyModel>` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431702/model-binding-with-variable-number-of-items-in-listt) for a demo

In your custom validation attribute you can then check the model easily and loop over the split percentage properties to see they total 100